# floatval returns 1 php error

Tags: php, variables, types, floating-point

I have a mysql table with float variables. I want to pass them to mongodb collection, but when i do it, php convert my float variables into string. I've tried to use this code to set variable type as float but it returns me 1 in every field:

```
foreach( $mytables as $table => $struct ) {
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT num_auto FROM XL_10331_EXPLOIT_251012 where flightid like '191622'") or die( mysql_error() );
  $count = mysql_num_rows( $sql );
  // If it has content insert all content
  if( $count > 0 ) {
    while($info = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
        $int_info=intval($info);
          $mosql[]=($int_info);
  }

   // Starts new collection on mongodb
  $collection = $modb->floatdb;

  $collection->insert(array('num_auto'=>$mosql));
```

i can't find my mistake, any help will be really appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: `$int_info=intval($info);` it looks like you're forcing your value to an int.

Comment: `floatval()` is in the question title, but not in the code.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: thanks for your help. actually i started to use php only one week ago, and it was really difficult times for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row` returns an array, not a value. So you have to use:

```
$int_info = (float)$info[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

`intval` will return only the integer part of a number (or a number in a string). Try casting the value to a float like

```
$float_value = (float) $sql_number;
```